# Jenkins permissions denied when copying files

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline, jhipster

I'm setting up a web application using jhipster.
I created a Jenkinsfile with the jhipster subgenerator which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node {
    stage('checkout') {
        checkout scm
    }

    docker.image('openjdk:8').inside('-u root -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Duser.home=./" --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock') {
        stage('check java') {
            sh "java -version"
        }

        stage('clean') {
            sh "chmod +x mvnw"
            sh "./mvnw clean"
        }

        stage('install tools') {
            sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-yarn -DnodeVersion=v6.11.3 -DyarnVersion=v1.1.0"
        }

        stage('yarn install') {
            sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:yarn"
        }

        stage('backend tests') {
            try {
                sh "./mvnw test"
            } catch(err) {
                throw err
            } finally {
                junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
            }
        }

        stage('frontend tests') {
            try {
                sh "./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:yarn -Dfrontend.yarn.arguments=test"
            } catch(err) {
                throw err
            } finally {
                junit '**/target/test-results/karma/TESTS-*.xml'
            }
        }

        stage('packaging') {
            sh "./mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests"
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true
        }

    }

    def dockerImage
    stage('build docker') {
        sh "cp -R src/main/docker target/"
        sh "cp target/*.war target/docker/"
        dockerImage = docker.build('test/testrepo', 'target/docker')
    }

    stage('publish docker') {
        docker.withRegistry('http://localhost:5000', 'docker-login') {
            dockerImage.push 'latest'
        }
    }
}
```

and jenkins fail (permissions denied) when executing:

```
sh "cp -R src/main/docker target/"
```

Here is the workspace directory on Jenkins:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   1565 Jan  2 18:58 .angular-cli.json
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins    475 Jan  2 18:58 .editorconfig
drwxr-xr-x    8 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jan  2 19:28 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   3374 Jan  2 18:58 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   1931 Jan  2 18:58 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x    4 root    root      4096 Jan  2 18:59 .m2
drwxr-xr-x    3 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jan  2 18:58 .mvn
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   1171 Jan  2 18:58 .yo-rc.json
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   1832 Jan  2 18:58 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   7052 Jan  2 18:58 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jenkins jenkins   7058 Jan  2 19:28 mvnw
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   5006 Jan  2 18:58 mvnw.cmd
drwxr-xr-x    3 root    root      4096 Jan  2 19:29 node
drwxr-xr-x 1120 root    root     36864 Jan  2 19:29 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   4434 Jan  2 18:58 package.json
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins  49644 Jan  2 18:58 pom.xml
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins     37 Jan  2 18:58 postcss.config.js
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins    117 Jan  2 18:58 proxy.conf.json
drwxr-xr-x    4 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jan  2 18:58 src
drwxr-xr-x    8 root    root      4096 Jan  2 19:30 target
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins    616 Jan  2 18:58 tsconfig-aot.json
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins    737 Jan  2 18:58 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins   3068 Jan  2 18:58 tslint.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jan  2 18:58 webpack
-rw-r--r--    1 jenkins jenkins 310798 Jan  2 19:29 yarn.lock
```

Should target directory have the user/group (root:root)?
What is the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: In your workspace, the folders owned by root have been created by the build process running inside docker container which is run by root  because of `inside('-u root` so you could try approach described at https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/

Comment: I removed '-u root' and now it's working

Comment: I think you should report it on github

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I've done it.

Answer (score 2):

jenkins has not the permission to write in target directory.

1-you can add jenkins as a second owner of your target directory like:
`chown -R root:jenkins target/`
(in your jenkinsfile: `sh 'chown -R root:jenkins target/'`

Comment: chown: invalid group: ‘root:jenkins’